# Beamer - Disable Fira Font in Metropolis Theme

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontspec, beamer-metropolis

Is it possible to disable the Fira Font in the Metropolis theme when using LuaTex and fontspec?
I would like to have the same fallback font that Metropolis uses when compiling with LaTex.

the MVE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}      

% Font configuration
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
     
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to make a local copy of `beamerfontthememetropolis.sty` with fira font related lines (lines 25--95) commented.

Comment: It did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the `moloch` theme, which is a more modern fork of the `metropolis` theme, but does not mess with the fonts:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
    \[
    abc xyz
    \]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you really need to use the original `metropolis` theme, you can set the sans font to `Latin Modern Sans` which will make the result look like the output you get if you compile with pdflatex:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
    \[
    abc xyz
    \]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]